# I am using Django By Default user Autheticate function but I am getting this Error "logout page not found"

Tags: python, html, django

[This is the image of the error that show up on Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkYMT.png)

There are 2 apps in my Djang project home and blog. is This is the code of signup/login and logout in my base.html file. I have searched a lot and try to fix it but i could'nt.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-2">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Welcome {{request.user}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"
                            style="background-color:rgb(237, 205, 243)">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <!-- Button to trigger SignUp modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mx-1" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#signupModal">
            SignUp
        </button>
        <!-- Button to trigger Login modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginModal">
            Login
        </button>
        {% endif %}
```

Here is urls.py file of home app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('search', views.search, name="search"),
    path('comment', views.comment, name='comment'),
    path('services', views.services, name='services'),
    path('appointment', views.appointment, name='appointment'),
    path('login', views.handleLogin, name="handleLogin"),
    path('signup', views.handleSignUp, name="handleSignUp"),
    path('logout', views.handleLogout, name="handleLogout"),
]
```

This is views.py file of home app

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from home.models import Contact, Comment, Post
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth  import authenticate,  login, logout    
def handleSignUp(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # Get the post parameters
        username=request.POST['username']
        email=request.POST['email']
        fname=request.POST['fname']
        lname=request.POST['lname']
        pass1=request.POST['pass1']
        pass2=request.POST['pass2']

        # check for errorneous input
        if len(username)>10:
            messages.error(request, " Your user name must be under 10 characters")
            return redirect('home')

        if not username.isalnum():
            messages.error(request, " User name should only contain letters and numbers")
            return redirect('home')
        if (pass1!= pass2):
             messages.error(request, " Passwords do not match")
             return redirect('home')
        
        # Create the user
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
        myuser.first_name= fname
        myuser.last_name= lname
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, " Your account has been successfully created")
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 - Not found")


def handleLogin(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # Get the post parameters
        loginusername=request.POST['loginusername']
        loginpass = request.POST['loginpass']

        user=authenticate(username= loginusername, password= loginpass)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Successfully Logged In")
            return redirect("home")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid credentials! Please try again")
            return redirect("home")

    return HttpResponse("404- Not found")
    #return HttpResponse("login")

def handleLogout(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "Successfully logged out")
    return redirect('home')
```

I don't know why the logout is not working properly. When i created the user authentication functionality, it was working well, but afterwards it started giving this error.

Comment: please try {% url 'logout' %} in your html file insted /logout

Comment: Yes i have already tried this but it gives the error ("NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.")

Comment: And when i tried with the same name as in the views that is "handleLogout", it again says page not found

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"
```

Do

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'handleLogout' %}"
```

Django has an inbuilt way of handling urls. Check Out the docs for the same [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: This is also not working for me.  It throws the same error.